# R: Exclude water bodies in SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, shapefile, r-raster

I have made a map of The Netherlands by using the getData function from the raster package. The getData function downloads geographical data for anywhere in the world. The downloaded data is class "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame".

I want to fill the land regions of the map with a light grey color, but when I try to fill in the color of the map, both land and water regions are filled in with color. There are several bodies of water that are bordered by dams, land, etc and they also get colored.

Here is how I create my map:

```
library(raster) #requires sp package
library(ggplot2)

#Download shapefile data for The Netherlands
Neth<-getData("GADM", country="NL", level=1)

#Set general theme options for the ggplot
theme_opts<-list(theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                       panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                       panel.background = element_blank(),
                       plot.background = element_blank(),
                       axis.line = element_blank(),
                       axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                       axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                       axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                       axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                       axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                       plot.title = element_blank()))

#Plot map of The Netherlands
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=Neth, aes(long,lat,group=group), fill="whitesmoke")+
  geom_path(data=Neth, aes(long,lat, group=group), color="black",
            size=0.3) +
  theme(aspect.ratio=1) + theme_opts
```

Here is an image of my map, I added the text "Water" to show some of the bodies of water:

[image: Map]
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I was able to solve the problem by only keeping the polygons for the provinces from my map:

```
#Only grab provinces
Neth <- Neth[Neth$TYPE_1 == "Province",] 

#Plot map of The Netherlands
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=Neth, aes(long,lat,group=group), fill="whitesmoke")+
  geom_path(data=Neth, aes(long,lat, group=group), color="black",
            size=0.3) +
  theme(aspect.ratio=1) + theme_opts
```

[image]